# Canada's Automatic Border Clearance for visiting citizens

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, canadian-citizens, toronto

I'm a dual citizen of Canada and the United States. I have a passport for both countries. I live in the United States, but I'm traveling to Canada for the holidays.

I've read that Pearson has a new automatic border clearance system for Canadian passport holders. I have a short connection through Pearson, so this system might be helpful.

Has anyone been in a similar situation and knows whether I will be able to use this system, as a visiting non-resident? I'm primarily wondering because online information suggests things like 'having receipts for purchases made abroad ready,' which makes it sound like it's intended for residents returning to Canada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use it.

Full information on the ABC (Automatic Border Clearance) system at Toronto Pearson is [available on their website](http://www.torontopearson.com/abc/#), but the key parts for you:

> **Canadian citizens** and permanent residents of Canada who **have a valid Canadian passport or** permanent resident card now have the
>   option of using an Automated Border Clearance kiosk upon their return
>   to Canada. The kiosks do not require pre-registration by guests or
>   payment of any membership fees.

So you won't have to do anything, as long as you have your Canadian passport with you, you should be able to make use of the ABC system.